# JMeter: Need to send an array of random values from a CSV file

Tags: arrays, jmeter

I have a CSV file, where topics of interest are present in each row:

[List of entries in a CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R4EP.png)

I want to pick any 4 random values from the CSV file and pass it as an array of strings to the request body, and some additional parameters as well, like below:

`{"interest":["Mobility Testing", "BI Modernization, "Data Monetization", "Big Data Testing"],"user_id":"8aafa3be-c19b-4355-88cb-1c068463790d","user_id_type":"wid"}`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the request body using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following code:

```
def entries = new HashSet()

def linesFromCSV = new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines()

while (entries.size() < 4) {
    entries.add(linesFromCSV.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, linesFromCSV.size())))
}

def payload = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([interest: entries]).toPrettyString()

vars.put('payload', payload)
```

Generated request body can be referenced as `${payload}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Apart from the array of the interest, I want to send few other parameters as well, like this: {"interest":["Mobility Testing", "BI Modernization"],"user_id":"8aafa3be-c19b-4355-88cb-1c068463790d","user_id_type":"wid"}. Can you please tell me how to add these other parameters as well, in the request body?