# JMeter: Passing multiple variables in toPrettyString() function

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

[JMeter: Need to send an array of random values from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76918898/jmeter-need-to-send-an-array-of-random-values-from-a-csv-file)

In continuation to the above question: Apart from passing random values from the CSV files in an array, some other parameters need to be passed as well, like below:

`{"interest":["Mobility Testing", "BI Modernization", "Data Monetization"],"user_id":"8aafa3be-c19b-4355-88cb-1c068463790d","user_id_type":"wid"}`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to add a couple more entries to the [LazyMap](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/api/org/apache/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html) which holds your request payload.

Change this line:

```
def payload = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([interest: entries]).toPrettyString()
```

to this one:

```
def payload = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([interest: entries,
                                           user_id: '8aafa3be-c19b-4355-88cb-1c068463790d',
                                           user_id_type: 'wid']).toPrettyString()
```

More information:

- [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates)